# How to copy all files to a folder from path in a txt file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a folder image (JPGE_Image) that contains jpg images as follows:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
...
100.jpg
```

I have other text file which contains the path of these selected jpeg images (not all images, just selected as 1.jpg, 3.jpg...) as

```
/home/users/JPGE_Image/1.jpg
/home/users/JPGE_Image/3.jpg
/home/users/JPGE_Image/5.jpg
...
/home/users/JPGE_Image/99.jpg
```

I want to copy selected image in the text file to other folder named `Selected_Folder`. How could I do it in python 2.7. Thank all. This is what I tried, but it does not get information from text file

```
import os
import shutil

srcfile = '/home/users/JPGE_Image/1.jpg'
dstroot = '/home/users/Selected_Folder'


assert not os.path.isabs(srcfile)
dstdir =  os.path.join(dstroot, os.path.dirname(srcfile))

os.makedirs(dstdir) # create all directories, raise an error if it already exists
shutil.copy(srcfile, dstdir)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why your code isn't working, but if this is just a one-time task, you may consider doing it in bash with this one liner: https://gist.github.com/a452c5672fa00837aee53f4380d5e379

Comment: What you mean by _does not get information_ , you get any error?

Comment: I think he means that the source path is set manually, instead of getting in txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to apply your logic on a line by line basis as follows:

```
import os
import shutil

text_file_list = 'my_text_file.txt'
dstroot = '/home/users/Selected_Folder'

try:
    os.makedirs(dstroot)
except OSError as e:     # catch exception if folder already exists
    pass

with open(text_file_list) as f_input:
    for srcfile_path in f_input:
        srcfile_path = srcfile_path.strip()
        srcfile = os.path.split(srcfile_path)[1]
        dstdir = os.path.join(dstroot, srcfile)
        shutil.copy(srcfile_path, dstdir)
```

As you read each line, use `strip()` to remove the trailing newline. Then use `os.path.split()` to get just the filename of the source. This can then be joined to your `dstdir`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Sorry about reply late. I tried your code and it got an error at `assert not os.path.isabs(srcfile)` as `assert not os.path.isabs('/media/users/data/JPGE_Image/2007_000032.jpg') AssertionError` where media means the disk. I am in ubuntu and my folder is in disk data.

Comment: Are all of your image files in a single folder? If so `makedirs()` would only be needed once on `dstroot`.

Comment: Yes. All image jpg in a folder which named as `JPGE_Image`. I want to copy images in the folder to another folder such that the name of copied image from the txt file

Comment: In that case, you just need to extract the source filename and join it to your dest folder. I have updated the script.

Comment: It is still not work. Let I explain it more clear. I have a folder image `JPGE_Image` which contains *.jpg images file. The folder located `/media/users/data/JPGE_Image/`. I also have a text file `my_text_file.txt` which contains the path of selected images  of the folder `JPGE_Image` (ex. /media/users/data/JPGE_Image/1.jpg, /media/users/data/JPGE_Image/3.jpg)` I want to copy the selected images from the  `JPGE_Image` folder to another folder such as `Selected_Folder` which located in `/media/users/data/Selected_Folder`. Output is that the folder `Selected_Folder` will have: `1.jpg, 3.jpg`

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the script, try now.

Comment: Thank you. I think my path contains `\n`, so it has error `No such file or directory: '/media/users/data/JPGE_Image/1.jpg\n'` How to remove it in python code? I am using rstrip('\n') method

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It worked well. I think it is better to insert a checking in the the line `os.makedirs(dstroot)` if the folder is exist

Answer (score 3):

You can read the paths from txt file line by line, like this:

```
with open(txtfile_path) as f:
    for srcfile in f:
        shutil.copy(srcfile, dstdir)
```